# How do I efficiently select the most recent record for a set of values TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

I have a set of tables each containing related data and I need to select the most recent set of records for each row in the source table.  There are millions of rows and I need to do this efficiently and so far im unable to return only the most recent date for a given number.

For example the current result for a given number is:

```
CampaignName    MobileNumber    Date

Campaign A      12345678910     12/02/2018 14:50:30
Campaign B      12345678910     05/02/2018 11:35:22
```

Only the row for Campaign A should be returned.

I'm essentially trying to get the most recent message sent for each mobile number and the campaign data for that message (each message is part of a campaign.

```
SELECT CC.campaignname,
       Co.mobilenumber,
       Max(M.msgcreatetime)
FROM   [Database].[dbo].[messages] M WITH(nolock)
       INNER JOIN dbo.messagecontact MC WITH(nolock)
               ON M.msgid = MC.messageid
       INNER JOIN dbo.campaigncontact Co WITH(nolock)
               ON Co.contactid = MC.contactid
       INNER JOIN dbo.campaign CC WITH(nolock)
               ON M.campaignid = CC.campaignid
GROUP  BY CC.campaignname,
          Co.mobilenumber
```

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What is wrong with that query? What does struggling mean?  Finally, you shouldn't be using `with (nolock) https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/top-3-mistakes-t-sql-developers-make/

Comment: No table named source.

Comment: ok thanks I've updated the post @Mazhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`top 1 with ties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`order by row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

Using `top 1 with ties` means you will get all the records where the value of the order by expression is the lowest.
Using `row_number() over(partition by Co.mobilenumber order by M.msgcreatetime desc)` will return 1 for the last date for each Co.mobilenumber, 2 for the second from last etc'.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       CC.campaignname,
       Co.mobilenumber,
       M.msgcreatetime
FROM   [Database].[dbo].[messages] M WITH(nolock)
       INNER JOIN dbo.messagecontact MC WITH(nolock)
               ON M.msgid = MC.messageid
       INNER JOIN dbo.campaigncontact Co WITH(nolock)
               ON Co.contactid = MC.contactid
       INNER JOIN dbo.campaign CC WITH(nolock)
               ON M.campaignid = CC.campaignid
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Co.mobilenumber ORDER BY M.msgcreatetime desc)
```